# When echoing $LINENO from a function, echo the line the function is being ran instead of the actual line

Tags: bash, shell

This is a follow-up to [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73989861/see-which-line-number-is-being-ran-in-a-sh-then-if-its-a-certain-line-run-ano) Someone told me how to use a DEBUG trap to run a command before every line, and I made function that executes in the trap. But, when echoing $LINENO from a function, it echos the literal line number. I need the line number that the function is being ran in. How do I do this?

More explaining, say a function `foo` was defined at line 25 and is ran at line 100. `foo` has the command `echo "$LINENO"` at line 26. Instead of echoing 26 (Where foo is defined and the echo command is located), I want it to echo 100 (Where the function `foo` is being ran).

And I'm pretty sure you don't need my code, since I just need help with getting the line number that the function is being executed in.
But, for the people who absolutely need to look at my code for some reason:
You probably won't find anything useful in my code.

```bash
getnextp() {
  i=0
  small=$1
  execute=
  while :; do
    ((i++))
    if [ "$i" -gt "$(sed -n '$=' plist)"]; then
      break
    fi
    line=$(sed $i'!d' plist)
    if [ "$line" == "$0" ]; then
      ((i++))
      ((i++))
      line=$(sed $i'!d' plist)
      if [ "$line" -lt "$small" ]; then
        small="$line"
        ((i--))
        line=$(sed $i'!d' plist)
        execute=$line
        ((i++))
      fi
    fi
  done
}
npl=999999999
step() {
  echo "Working."
  echo $LINENO
  if [ "$(cat plist)" == *"$0"* ]; then
    getnextp $1
    if [ "$LINENO" == "$small" ]; then
      cd ../
      ./packages/$execute
    fi
  fi
}
trap "step $npl" DEBUG
```

Comment: Please add your desired output to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus Hopefully my edit helps

Comment: You could always do subtraction.  Store the value of $LINENO at the start of the function in a variable (eg `base=$LINENO`) and refer to `$(( LINENO - base ))`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I made some more edits because I think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Remember how I mentioned `BASH_LINENO`? Unlike LINENO itself, BASH_LINENO is an array; you can get prior stack frames by looking deeper in it.

Comment: BTW, `[ foo = *bar* ]` doesn't work; fnmatch-style matching is a `[[` feature that `[` doesn't have. (And stay away from `==` in `[` altogether -- it's a habit that leads to bugs whenever you're writing code for baseline-POSIX shells; the standard-compliant string comparison operator is `=`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy AAAAUGH I always forget the double brackets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, the array variable BASH_LINENO stores the trace.  eg:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() { 
    echo at $LINENO in foo, called from ${BASH_LINENO[0]}
    echo which was called from line ${BASH_LINENO[1]}; 
}
bar() { foo; }
bar
```